# GridView and placeholders that never disappear in Windows 8 and Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8.1

I have an Universal App targeting Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1. Both apps use GridView to display data.

Sometimes, instead of the actual items, just the placeholders are shown. This is known behavior, GridView showing placeholders when scrolling and it does not have enough time to render the actual items and eventually renders them.

But in my case, the placehores just stay there, GridView never renders the actual times. This happens on both Windows Phone and Windiws, so I guess the GridView must be the problem.

Anyone has experienced this? Any clue would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot, notice the gray rectangles render instead of actual items (like the first one).

[image]

The GridDefinition is quite simple:

```
   <GridView               
            Grid.Column="2"                
            Padding="0,0,0,96"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TrackListingTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}" />
```

The Item template is just a grid with a TextBlock and some images.

The memory footprint is also ok, about 100 MB.

Comment: So, this GridView works correctly sometimes? Also, I don't think there are any placeholders by default (or at least I can't remember at the moment), so what are these and where do they come from? And it may be a good idea to share the item template as well (not sure if it's related but just in case).

Comment: ShowsScrollingPlaceholders is true by default on the GridView

Comment: Oh... I haven't seen this before. I'd guess the problem may be caused by the GridView's parent or other ancestor UI elements. Or if you've changed the GridView's default Style/ControlTemplate - something in that change may be a problem.

Comment: I made no changes to Style/ControlTemplate and the parent of the GridView is a simple Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a great solution, but setting `ShowsScrollingPlaceholders=false` disables all the placeholders. According to the documentation, empty space should be visible instead of items but this is not the case, the whole GridView frezees for a seconds instead.